# how to pull mysql data from multiple tables with ORDER BY date field?

Tags: php, mysql

i am seeking help on a query which shows movement of a stock item for a particular itemid.

Table1 Name: saleitems Fields: **itemid**, saledate, qty

Table2 Name: purchaseitems Fields: **itemid**, purchasedate, qty

Table3 Name: stocktransfers Fields: **itemid**, trfdate, from, to, qty

I want to pull out mysql data from all three tables and sort them based in the date fields. Any help is much appreciated.

The expected output should look like below[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of the data and the expected result

Comment: @ManseUK added the expected output details

Comment: @mmdel Where do the `date` and `type` columns come from ? ie which tables ?

Comment: @ManseUK The date columns are present in the sale table and also in the purchase table and also in the saleitems and purchaseitems tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from saleitems,purchaseitems,stocktransfers
where your condition order by saledate,purchasedate,trfdate
```

you can use order by clause as given select whichever fields you want based on condition or join as per your logic and use order by

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(select itemid, "SALES" as type, saledate as dt, qty from salesitems)
union
(select itemid, "PURCHASE" as type, purchasedate as dt, qty from purchaseitems)
union
(select itemid, "STOCKTRANSFER" as type, trfdate as dt, qty from stocktransferitems)
order by dt;
```

I hope, I got your question right.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
select * from salesitems a 
inner join purchaseitems b on a.itemid=b.itemid 
inner join stocktransfer c on a.item_id=c.item_id 
order by a.saledate,b.purchasedate,c.trfdate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.itemid,a.saledate,a.qty,b.purchasedate,b.qty,c.trfdate,c.from,c.to,c.qty
FROM saleitems a INNER JOIN purchaseitems b
        ON a.itemid = b.itemid
    INNER JOIN stocktransfers c
        ON a.itemid = b.itemid
WHERE a.itemid = 10
ORDER BY a.saledate , b.purchasedate , c.trfdate
```